# How to access pointer to member parameter in C++ class template?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a C++ class template that takes advantage of a pointer to member parameter but compilation fails. How do I access the pointer to member parameter from within the template?

```
class Base {
public:
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

template<int Base::* T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  int Get() { return *T; }  <--- Does not work
};

Derived<&Base::foo> test;
printf("Value = %i\n", test.Get());
```

The compilation error from Clang is `indirection requires pointer operand ('int Test::*' invalid)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return this->*T;
```

(Why `T`? It's not a type.)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
int Get() { return this->*T; }
```

`.*` and `->*` are the operators for dereferencing pointers-to-members.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry you're 1 mn later than the accepted answer :)

Comment: @Pol: You can always change the accepted answer, if you find a newer answer to be more helpful, complete, etc.